# Where does my code go wrong, elementary Python+Selenium+chromedriver issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My project requires selenium and after quite a bit of struggling I kept failing to correctly set up selenium/chromedriver on my PC and the code [My initial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H2NJ.png) kept coming back with a 'DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object'. [Result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYmMd.png)

So, I copied code from a similar question's answer and it worked as expected! [Working solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKalT.png)

Could someone please explain why my code does not work, and why his/hers does?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add .exe to your path variable, so it would be:

```
path = '/User/iop/Downloads/chromedriver.exe'
```